# With Visual C , typeid throw an exception but only in debug mode

Tags: visual-c++, cmake, windows-7-x64, debug-symbols, typeid

The following code comes from an answer to question 398069. It works very well for me under Linux and also under Windows in optim mode. Unfortunately, my app crashes under Windows and I have to debug it...

```
template <class T>
T *set_the_global(T *candidate)
{
std::map<std::string,void*>::iterator r = MainFactoriesMap::mainFactoriesMap().find(std::string(typeid(*candidate).name()));
...
}
```

In debug mode (Windows, with qtcreator, cmake 2.8.2, Visual C++ 10, Qt and boost are available as debug and not debug), the call to typeid, which occurs before entering main, crashes, throwing an exception it seems. I forced the use of /GR option. It makes no difference...

I put below the calls to compiler and linker in debug and output modes. Note that I tried to compile everything under Visual Studio but it fails (but this will be another question).

Optim build: it works

```
c:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2.0\VC\bin\amd64\cl.exe    /Zc:wchar_t- /EHsc /GR /MD /O2 /Ob2 /D NDEBUG -IE:\Projets\Amose\Sources\lima_common\src -IC:\Qt\v4.8.2\include -IC:\Qt\v4.8.2\include\QtXml -IC:\Qt\v4.8.2\include\QtCore -IC:\PROGRA~1\boost\BOOST_~1\include -Ic:\amose\include    -D DEBUG_CD -D WIN32 -D QT_NO_KEYWORDS -Dlima_common_factory_EXPORTS -DQT_DLL -DQT_XML_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK -DLIMA_FACTORY_EXPORTING -DQT_NO_DEBUG /TP /FoCMakeFiles\lima-common-factory.dir\AmosePluginsManager.cpp.obj /FdC:\amose-vcbuild\lima-common\src\common\AbstractFactoryPattern\lima-common-factory.pdb -c E:\Projets\Amose\Sources\lima_common\src\common\AbstractFactoryPattern\AmosePluginsManager.cpp
```

...
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_dll c:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2.0\VC\bin\amd64\link.exe  @CMakeFiles\lima-common-factory.dir\objects1.rsp  /out:lima-common-factory.dll /implib:lima-common-factory.lib /pdb:C:\amose-vcbuild\lima-common\src\common\AbstractFactoryPattern\lima-common-factory.pdb /dll /version:0.0  /STACK:10000000 /machine:x64  /INCREMENTAL:NO -LIBPATH:C:\PROGRA~1\boost\BOOST_~1\lib -LIBPATH:c:\amose\lib ..\QsLog\lima-common-qslog.lib ..\misc\lima-common-misc.lib ..\Data\lima-common-data.lib ..\QsLog\lima-common-qslog.lib C:\Qt\v4.8.2\lib\QtXml4.lib C:\Qt\v4.8.2\lib\QtCore4.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib

Debug build: it fails

```
c:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2.0\VC\bin\amd64\cl.exe    /Zc:wchar_t- /EHsc /GR /D_DEBUG /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 -IE:\Projets\Amose\Sources\lima_common\src -IC:\Qt\v4.8.2\include -IC:\Qt\v4.8.2\include\QtXml -IC:\Qt\v4.8.2\include\QtCore -IC:\PROGRA~1\boost\BOOST_~1\include -Ic:\amose-debug\include    -D DEBUG_CD -D WIN32 -D QT_NO_KEYWORDS -Dlima_common_factory_EXPORTS -DQT_DLL -DQT_XML_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK -DLIMA_FACTORY_EXPORTING -DQT_DEBUG /TP /FoCMakeFiles\lima-common-factory.dir\AmosePluginsManager.cpp.obj /FdC:\amose-vcbuild\lima-common-debug\src\common\AbstractFactoryPattern\lima-common-factoryd.pdb -c E:\Projets\Amose\Sources\lima_common\src\common\AbstractFactoryPattern\AmosePluginsManager.cpp
```

...
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_dll c:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2.0\VC\bin\amd64\link.exe  @CMakeFiles\lima-common-factory.dir\objects1.rsp  /out:lima-common-factoryd.dll /implib:lima-common-factoryd.lib /pdb:C:\amose-vcbuild\lima-common-debug\src\common\AbstractFactoryPattern\lima-common-factoryd.pdb /dll /version:0.0  /STACK:10000000 /machine:x64  /debug /INCREMENTAL -LIBPATH:C:\PROGRA~1\boost\BOOST_~1\lib -LIBPATH:c:\amose-debug\lib ..\QsLog\lima-common-qslogd.lib ..\misc\lima-common-miscd.lib ..\Data\lima-common-datad.lib ..\QsLog\lima-common-qslogd.lib C:\Qt\v4.8.2\lib\QtXmld4.lib C:\Qt\v4.8.2\lib\QtCored4.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib

Showing the debuging session using qtcreator:

[image]

Comment: Well, debug it.  Document everything you see in the Output window.

Comment: Well ,I tried to debug it, countless time since one full week! under qtcreator I just get the program stoped at this line and cannot get any other information (see the debug session screenshot linked). I tried using Visual Studio but there, it does not link (I asked for help on this in another question). I come from Linux and obtaining a clear image of what is happening  under Windows is somewhat difficult. I think I have a problem very specific to the platform and searched a lot before asking for help.

Comment: Are you mixing libraries from different compilers or under Visual Studio are you mixing Debug and Release in the same application. If so remember that this is unsafe.

Comment: I don't think so. boost and qt have both debug and non-debug versions and cmake is setup with CMAKE_BUILD_TYPË=Debug. So, it should select the right ones. DependencyWalker show `boost_*-VC100-MT-GD-1_10.dll` and `QTCORED4.DLL`. Everything else is our code.

Comment: Was qt compiled from the same compiler that you are using. This also can cause problems. As a result I build Qt myself with the compiler that I am using. Currently that is Visual Studio 2010 x64 with CMake-2.8.X to generate my projects. I am using Qt-4.8.2.

Comment: @drescherjm:No, I use prebuilt Qt from Nokia. What is strange is that this call to typeid works as needed in optim but throws in debug as if  there is no RTTI support in debug. This gives me the idea to test thorougly RTTI support on a simple example with the various setups I tried .

Comment: If you are using a prebuilt one from nokia make sure it is the one for your compiler version.

Comment: @drescherjm: in fact, I remember now that I compiled it myself too. With exactly the same configuration as you.